# VSCode - Align All Chars Prettify Settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Prettier (VSCode) does a great job beautifying my code on save. 
There is one feature that I consider important in code formatting which I can't find in Prettier.
I want to align chars `=, :, =>`, etc., in multiple lines like [this VSCode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=annsk.alignment) does.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The universal answer to questions like "How can I make Prettier format my code in such a way that ...?" is "You can't."

Prettier's purpose is to facilitate collaboration in projects and teams by taking care of code style, not to be a customizable code formatter that does whatever the user wants. In other words, the formatting it produces isn't really customizable, and this is intentional. Read more [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html). If you need that degree of control over formatting, you're likely not the target audience for Prettier.

This specific code style (alignment) that you want to have is considered diff-unfriendly (e.g., see [here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#formatting-horizontal-alignment) or [here](https://google.github.io/swift/#horizontal-alignment)). Prettier's line breaking algorithm by itself has similar problems (e.g, adding one argument to a call might lead to a multiline diff if the line becomes too long), but they're inevitable, so Prettier's strategy is to compensate for that by avoiding other diff-unfriendly things.

Answer (score 0):

You could always utilise the Alt key or Code Maid to clean up.

If you hold the Alt Key and drag down then you can highlight the spacing to either remove or align your code.

[image]